# Bulkification help with apex called from trigger

Tags: apex, trigger, bulkification

I am slowly learning Apex and have created the following method called from a trigger to update the work order address fields by copying the data from a related address object.

As I now understand it, it is bad practice to do the for loop and soql inside the other for loop.  Unfortunately I don't know how to improve this, could anyone help?

Thanks,

```
public static void populateWorkOrderAddress(List<WorkOrder> newWorkOrder){

        String WorkOrderID;
        for(WorkOrder i:newWorkOrder) {
           if (i.related_address__c != NULL){
                for (Addressing__c adr : [SELECT address_line_1__c, address_line_2__c, address_line_3__c, address_line_4__c, post_code__c FROM Addressing__c WHERE id = : i.related_address__c]){
                    i.Related_Address__c = adr.Id;
                    i.Work_Order_Address_Line_1__c = adr.Address_Line_1__c;
                    i.Work_Order_Address_Line_2__c = adr.Address_Line_2__c;
                    i.Work_Order_Address_Line_3__c = adr.Address_Line_3__c;
                    i.Work_Order_Address_Line_4__c = adr.Address_Line_4__c;
                    i.Work_Order_Address_Post_Code__c = adr.post_code__c;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is an approach to handle query out of `for` loop.

```
public static void populateWorkOrderAddress(List<WorkOrder> newWorkOrder){

    Set<Id> relatedAddIds = new Set<Id>();
    for(WorkOrder i:newWorkOrder)
    {
        if(i.related_address__c != NULL)
        {   
            relatedAddIds.add(i.related_address__c);
        }
    }

    Map<Id, Addressing__c> queryMap=new Map<Id, Addressing__c>([SELECT address_line_1__c, 
                            address_line_2__c, address_line_3__c, address_line_4__c, post_code__c 
                            FROM Addressing__c 
                            WHERE id IN:relatedAddIds]);


    for(WorkOrder i:newWorkOrder) {
    {
        if (i.related_address__c != NULL){
            Addressing__c adr = queryMap.get(i.related_address__c));
            i.Related_Address__c = adr.Id;
            i.Work_Order_Address_Line_1__c = adr.Address_Line_1__c;
            i.Work_Order_Address_Line_2__c = adr.Address_Line_2__c;
            i.Work_Order_Address_Line_3__c = adr.Address_Line_3__c;
            i.Work_Order_Address_Line_4__c = adr.Address_Line_4__c;
            i.Work_Order_Address_Post_Code__c = adr.post_code__c;
        }
    }                   

}
```

Comment: You beat me to it! The only thing I would add would be a check that the Id is contained in queryMap so you don't get any NullPointerExceptions.

    if(i.related_address__c != NULL) {
        if(queryMap.keyset().contains(i.related_address__c) { ...

Comment: It will never be null as `relatedAddIds` is storing the `Addressing__c` ids and query is retrieving record values from that id. Extra `contains` check not needed

Answer (score 1):

The general solution is to

1. Use a loop to iterate over your primary object (`WorkOrder` in your case), and gather the data you're using (to filter your query) into a `List` or `Set`
2. Perform your query (outside of all loops)
3. Loop over the results of your query to build a `Map` that relates the data you used to filter your query to the corresponding record(s) of your query
4. Loop over your primary object again

In practice, that could look something like this

```
// I use a set here because order doesn't matter and it's a lot easier
//   to remove a specific thing (like NULL) from a set
Set<Id> relatedAddresses = new Set<Id>();
for(WorkOrder wo :newWorkOrder){
    relatedAddresses.add(wo.related_address__c);
}

Map<Id, Addressing__c> addressIdToAddressMap = new Map<Id, Addressing__c>();

// In your particular case, since you're using the Id of Addressing__c, you don't 
//   really need this loop.
// You could simply initialize the map with the query results like
//   addressIdToAddressMap = new Map<Id, Addressing__c>([SELECT <desired fields> FROM 
//   Addressing__c WHERE <filter condition]);
// 
for(Addressing__c addr :[SELECT Id, address_line_1__c FROM Addressing__c WHERE Id IN :relatedAddresses]){
    addressIdToAddressMap.put(addr.Id, addr);
}

Addressing__c currentAddressRecord;
for(WorkOrder wo :newWorkOrder){
    // Checking to see if related_address__c is null and/or if the resulting
    //   currentAddressRecord is null would be wise
    currentAddressRecord = addressIdToAddressMap.get(wo.related_address__c);
    wo.someField__c = currentAddressRecord.otherField__c;
}
```